# Matlab: Skip items in legend of bodeplot

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Short question: How can I do a legend to only certain bode plots in a figure? The following does not work:

```
figure;
hold on; 
h1=bodeplot(1/tf('s'));
h2=bodeplot(12/tf('s'));
legend(h1,'1/s');
```

Edit / Background: I have a loop somewhere in my script which plots 50 bode plots in the same colour (blue) to show how a plant can deviate. Then I want to plot some upper (red) and lower (green) bound and an average (yellow) inside the graph. And of course I want to do a legend: blue line: all plants; red: upper bound; green: lower bound; yellow: average

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please add a handdraw screenshot of what you want to have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can obtain the axes-handles by

```
h = findobj(gcf,'type','Axes');
```

and then use in your case

```
legend(h(2),'1/s');
```

Note, `findobj` returns the objects in reverse order.

The second graph (phase) can be obtained by `h(1)`.

To select certain lines use:

```
h = flipud(findobj(gcf,'type','axes'));

hl1 = flipud(findobj(h(1),'type','Line'));
hl2 = flipud(findobj(h(2),'type','Line'));

% Example
legend(h(1),hl1(1),'1/s');
legend(h(2),hl2(2),'12/s');
```

or as another example

```
legend(h(1),hl1(1:2),'1/s','12/s');
legend(h(2),hl2(1),'1/s');
```

Comment: I doubt this is the right solution? no matter what you choose here `h(...)` you wont get the red plot in the legend. Both plots are on the same axis.

Comment: I understood it in the way, that he wanted to have the separate legends in the upper and lower bode plots.

Comment: I understood that he for example just wants a legend for the second plot, and this is not trivial. (at least not, if one wants to stay with bodeplot)

Comment: Thank you for your post, Nemesis. But thewaywewalk is right. I want to do a legend specifically for one bode plot (e.g. for the second one).

Comment: @Nemesis: Wow thanks. That helped me a lot. But why is there such a strange order if I use a third plot e.g. h3=bodeplot(3/tf('s')) and then I use your script, but legend(h(2),hl1(3),'3/s'); does not work. I would need hl1(2) instead.

Comment: @Sebastian As mentioned, `findobj` returns the reverse order. See again my edit.

Comment: @Nemesis: You are right. Thank you a lot for your fast help.

Answer (score 1):

For such uses you can use Robust Control Toolbox too.

```
a = ureal('a',6,'PlusMinus',5);% nominal 6 plus minus 5
H = tf(a,[1 0]);% Try to avoid tf('s') as much as you can
bode(gridureal(H,10)); % 10 equidistant samples
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I know the robust control box very well. But in my specific case it is not possible, because it is a collection of 50 plants (some frds, some tfs etc.). An uncertainty model with parameteric uncertainties would be too imprecise in that case. I have a question to your post. You said that I should avoid tf('s'). Why?

Comment: @Sebastian My pleasure. That's because internally matlab represents `s` as a gss (a descriptor system with a nontrivial E matrix). If your system is complicated enough you'll get spurious noncausal states for no reason other than internal inaccuracies. At least fix the system to a variable `s=tf('s')` and use it if you absolutely have to and `minreal()` as often as possible.